# JPA: how to set up key for historizing entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Within JPA in Spring Boot / Spring Data, I want to set up an entity class.

The business requirement is to historize the processing of documents that exist once per year each.

The processing is performed in a bulk: so all documents are processed together: there is *one* `processingTimestamp` for all documents in the database for each processing sequence.

Later on, I want to access only the most recently processed document, but keep the previously processed documents for reference.

I see the following alternatives:

1. Use a composite key

   ```
   @Id
   private String documentId;

   @Id
   private String yearOfDocumentCreation;

   @Id
   private java.sql.Timestamp processingTimestamp;
   ```
2. Use an auto generated key

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;

   private String documentId;

   private String yearOfDocumentCreation

   private java.sql.Timestamp processingTimestamp;
   ```

Which alternative is better/best practise regarding

1. Handling (e.g. storing a list of documents as a bulk that were read before from the database and avoiding duplicates in the database)
2. Performance

Or do I miss other alternatives/aspects?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a single Long primary key, if you will need to make a foreign key to this table.
To avoid dublicates you can make a unique constraint on the 3 required columns.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I achieve that existing `(documentId, yearOfDocumentCreation, processingTimestamp)` combinations get replaced automatically when a new entry with the same combination of values is persisted?

Comment: You can create a composite unique constrain to avoid replacing same entry. if you want to replace it,  you need to find existing entry by thees three columns, if exist then update, else - create new. The unique constraint will be an index, to find by index is not too expensive.